# Можно ли начинать предложение с глагола?

Tags: глаголы

Можно ли начинать повествовательное предложение с глагола? Например: "Прошла конференция во Владивостоке, участники обсудили ряд вопросов".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это исключительно вопрос стилистики. Каких-либо жестких ограничений с точки зрения правил русского языка здесь нет.

Если говорить о приведенном Вами примере, то в данном конкретном случае уместнее изменить порядок слов:

> Во Владивостоке прошла конференция, участники обсудили ряд вопросов.

Но в другой ситуации можно было бы начать фразу именно так, как это сделали Вы. Например:

> Прошла конференция во Владивостоке, затем состоялись неформальные
>   встречи в Москве и Санкт-Петербурге.

Во многих случаях с помощью порядка слов можно привнести определенное эмоциональное наполнение.
Сравните:

> Пошел дождь.

и

> Дождь пошел...

Даже если бы в конце второй фразы не было многоточия, в ней все равно присутствовал бы некоторый оттенок задумчивости (при условии, что общий контекст повествования не указывал бы на что-либо иное). Первая же фраза просто информирует о погодном явлении.